# move icons inside anchor element doesn't work?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to move icons within anchor elements without target any icon but it doesn't work..

I would really appreciate any information any of you can give me about it !

```css
html {
 font-size: 2.5em;
}
body {
 background-color: #fff;
 padding: 25px;
 text-align: center;
}

.icon-button {
 background-color: orange;
 border-radius: 2.6rem;
 display: inline-block;
 font-size: 1.3rem;
 height: 2.6rem;
 line-height: 2.6rem;
 margin: 0 5px;
 text-align: center;
 width: 2.6rem;
}
```

```html
<head>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="<head>
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>

<a href="#" class="icon-button twitter"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a>
<a href="#" class="icon-button facebook"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a>
<a href="#" class="icon-button pinterest"><i class="fa fa-pinterest"></i></a>
```

Comment: How do you need your result to be?

Comment: Seems like i can change the line height just fine - you might have some css that overwrites it though

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/s2dzL790/

Comment: stylesheets should be included in the head of a document - not in a header tag.  Also it is unclear what your problem is - the line height is 5rem as set

Comment: I wanna move icons verticaly using line-height to center it inside <a> tag without target it (icons)

Answer (score 0):

Add line-height for icon

```
a i {
  line-height: 5rem;
}
```